# Lineplot and relplot in the same figure in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, seaborn, figure

I would like to plot two datasets in the same figure in seaborn, however, it doesn't work.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(1, 36)
x2 =[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20,
20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]

y = [6431, 6449, 6466, 6483, 6499, 6515, 6530, 6545, 6559, 6572, 6586,
6599, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605,
6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605]

y2 = [6437, 6513, 6499, 6540, 6499, 6472, 6635, 6534, 6532, 6579, 6575,
      6575, 6509, 6660, 6540, 6693, 6520, 6691, 6580, 6627]

df1 = {'x': x, 'y': y}
df2 = {'x': x2, 'y': y2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6.68))

sns.set(style="ticks", font='arial', font_scale=2)

sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", 
            palette = 'PuBuGn_d', ax=ax, data=df1)
sns.relplot(x="x", y="y",
        palette = 'cmap', ax = ax, data=df2)

plt.show()
```

it should seem like:
[image]

is it possible to format y-axis with thousands separator?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential workaround. Switching the positions of `sns.relplot` and `sns.lineplot` gives the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(1, 36)
x2 =[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20,
20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]

y = [6431, 6449, 6466, 6483, 6499, 6515, 6530, 6545, 6559, 6572, 6586,
6599, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605,
6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605]

y2 = [6437, 6513, 6499, 6540, 6499, 6472, 6635, 6534, 6532, 6579, 6575,
      6575, 6509, 6660, 6540, 6693, 6520, 6691, 6580, 6627]

df1 = {'x': x, 'y': y}
df2 = {'x': x2, 'y': y2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

sns.set(style="ticks", font='arial', font_scale=1)

sns.relplot(x="x", y="y", color='orange', data=df2)
sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=df1)

plt.show()
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html#classes-and-functions-for-making-complex-graphics). This means it can potentially create many subplots for diverse combinations of columns. Therefore, it always creates its own figure, even when only 1 subplot is needed.  Replacing `relplot` with the underlying [`scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) solves the problem.

To get a thousands separator, you can use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) with a function that converts the number to a string with a [komma in the format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/).

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
x = np.arange(1, 36)
x2 = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]
y = [6431, 6449, 6466, 6483, 6499, 6515, 6530, 6545, 6559, 6572, 6586, 6599, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605, 6605]
y2 = [6437, 6513, 6499, 6540, 6499, 6472, 6635, 6534, 6532, 6579, 6575, 6575, 6509, 6660, 6540, 6693, 6520, 6691, 6580, 6627]

df1 = {'x': x, 'y': y}
df2 = {'x': x2, 'y': y2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6.68))

sns.set(style="ticks", font='arial', font_scale=2)

sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y",
             palette='PuBuGn_d', ax=ax, data=df1)
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y",
                color='orange', ax=ax, data=df2, s=150)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: f'{x:,.0f}'))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]